# WebDriverManager.Net not running the version of Chromedriver for my local version of chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I am wanting to update chromedriver to the correct version of chrome that I am running. I have currently seen that other people have had this issue, and have added the "--remote-allow-origins=*" argument to the option. But it is not working for me, here is my code below.

```
var defaultManage = new DriverManager();
defaultManage.SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser);
var defaultOptions = new ChromeOptions();
defaultOptions.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
defaultOptions.AddArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
testDriver = new ChromeDriver(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), defaultOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
testDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
testDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
return testDriver;
```

I am getting the following message '*This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 112
Current browser version is 114.0.5735.110 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)'*

I removed the latest chromedriver that I had updated manually and get this error message:

*bin\Debug\net6.0\chromedriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at [http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html'](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html%27)*

Comment: Why not uninstall the current ChromeDriver and install it via: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: It defeats the purpose of webdrivermanager, we have an automated test running on azure, but I always have to update the chromedriver manually when it changes...this is supposed to stop you from having to do that, and run against the version of chrome that is on your pc, or that is on azure.

Comment: If I remember correctly, WebDriverManager.NET calls https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_114 (replace "114" with the major version of your current browser installation). Maybe at the time you ran the test ChromeDriver didn't have a v114 driver version available yet?

Comment: Although it might be including the minor and patch versions as well in the URL.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Running into the same issue where tests run in Azure and they fail so I need to manually update the version of ChromeDriver because DriverManager isn't doing the job.